# VSCode not running task on folder open

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I'm using TypeScript and constantly having to start the `tsc-watch` task manually. According to to the Blog VSCode v1.30+ can [automatically run tasks when a folder is opened](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_30#_run-on-folder-open) but this is not working for me (v1.33.1) - I open my folder and no task is running.
[image]

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "typescript",
            "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
            "isBackground": true,
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$tsc"
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "typescript",
            "label": "TypeScript Compiler Watcher Thingy...",
            "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
            "option": "watch",
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$tsc-watch"
            ],
            "runOptions": {
                "runOn": "folderOpen"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

BTW: Also tried [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=philfontaine.autolaunch) and it also did not start the task.

Comment: It would have prompted you for permissions to autorun the task the first time you opened it with that task config. It's possible you clicked "no" by mistake. Try running the command "Allow automatic tasks in folder"

Comment: I have the same problem with "tsc watch" 2019.11

Comment: Does anyone found working solution ???

Comment: `Ctrl+SHIFT+P` and `Tasks: Manage Automatic Tasks in Folder` and choose `Allow Automatic Tasks in folder` and restart VS Code

Answer (score 12):

This work in VSCode v. 1.42.1 my tasks.json

```
    {
     "version": "2.0.0",
     "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "typescript",
            "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
            "label": "TypeScript Compiler Watching...",
            "option": "watch",
            "presentation": {
                "echo": true,
                "reveal": "silent",
                "focus": false,
                "panel": "shared"
            },
            "isBackground": true,
            "runOptions": {"runOn": "folderOpen"},
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$tsc-watch"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
   }
```

If this still not work on project folder open try Ctrl+shift+P and `Tasks: Manage Automatic Tasks in Folder` and choose "Allow Automatic Tasks in folder" on main project folder or running folder.